# Como enviar um post do Android para Asp.net Core?

Tags: android, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

tenho uma aplicação em asp.net Core que deve receber um Post via android e não estou conseguindo. Sempre ocorre um erro no android que a página não foi encontrada.

> classe do objeto no Asp que receberá o Post enviado pelo android

```
    public class Localizacao
{
    public string motoristaId { get; set; }
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string lon { get; set; }
}
```

> Controller do Asp que receberá o Post

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AtualizaLocalizacaoMotorista([FromBody] Localizacao localizacao)
    {
        var sa = new JsonSerializerSettings();         
        return Json(localizacao, sa);
    }
```

> código no android para enviar o Post

```
import android.content.Context;
```

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class TryLogin  extends AsyncTask {
private Context context;

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    final String motoristaId = params[0];
    if (null == motoristaId) {
        return "motoristaId não informado";
    }

    HttpURLConnection connection;
    OutputStreamWriter request = null;

    URL url = null;
    String response = null;
    String parameters = "motoristaId=" + motoristaId;

    try {
        url = new  URL("https://MINHA_URL");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        //connection.setRequestProperty("X-DreamFactory-Api-Key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        //connection.setRequestProperty("X-DreamFactory-Session-Token", "key");
        //connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "auth");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");


        request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        request.write(parameters);
        request.flush();
        request.close();
        connection.connect();
        String line = "";
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        // Response from server after login process will be stored in response variable.
        response = sb.toString();
        /**
         Não podemos interar com a tela!, vamos mandar para o método onPostExecute
         */
        // Toast.makeText(this,"Message from Server:"+ response, 0).show();
        isr.close();
        reader.close();
        return response;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    }

}

/**
 * Este método irá rodar na Thread de UI após executar a ação!
 *
 * @param s
 */

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    if (s != null) {
        Toast.makeText(context , s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

> Da Activity eu chamo com o parâmetro

```
new TryLogin().execute("dsfsdfsdfsdfds");
```

Comment: Acredito que o erro seja por no ASP estar esperando `FormBody` e no android estar enviando `application/json`. Porem recomendo você utilizar a lib Retrofit no android para efetuar as chamadas Http, é muito mais simples. Link Retrofit: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Desculpe a demora, estava fazendo vários testes. Eu já tinha tentado o Retrofit, mas achei complexo. Estudei mais esse recurso e consegui andar no projeto. Agora é fazer o upload e download de imagens do celular para a API em asp.core. Obrigado pelo apoio. Com o retrofit a código ficou bem mais limpo e simpes de entender. A questão do [FromBody] no asp eu removi, tinha colocado pela própria orientações das bucas que fiz, mas tirei agora.